# Calling a local json file and parsing data in ReactJS

Tags: json, reactjs

I have the following json file. Right now, i have kept this in my ReactJS project itself locally. Later on planning to move in a server location.

abtestconfig.json

```
[
    { 
        "abtestname": "expAButton",
        "traffic": 1,
        "slices": 
        [
            "orange",
            "blue"
        ]
    },
    { 
        "abtestname": "expTextArea",
        "traffic": 0.5,
        "slices": 
        [
            "lightgrey",
            "yellow"
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to read and get data and parse it and apply in a function. I got some reference sample code and trying to use `fetch` api to react json file with the following code.

After reading this json file, i will have to pass the data in `abtest` function, as you can see now it's sending with hard coded value `abtest('expAButton', 0.75).slices('orange', 'blue').run(function ()`

I have the following doubts and wanted to get your guidance / clarification.

**1. Is it correct way to read json file using `fetch` api? Is there any other best approach?**

**2. When I use `fetch` api like mentioned below, console log displays `GET http://localhost:8080/abtesting/abtestconfig.json 404 (Not Found)`**

app.jsx file:

```
import './abtesting/abtestconfig.json';    

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.onClickNewUser = this.handleNewUser.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            bgColor: '',
            data: []         
        }         
     };
     handleNewUser (event) {
        abtest.clear();
        window.location.reload();
     }

    render() {
        return (
                <Helmet
                />                 
                <p><b>A/B Testing Experience</b></p>

                    <div className="DottedBox">
                        <p><button id = "newUserButton" onClick = {this.onClickNewUser} style={{backgroundColor:"red"}}>Welcome and click here</button></p>

                    </div>
        );

    }

handleClick () {

        abtest('expAButton', 0.75).slices('orange', 'blue').run(function () {
            expAButton.style.backgroundColor = this.slice.name;
        });
}

setStyle (stylecolor) {
        this.setState({
            bgColor: stylecolor
          })
    }

componentDidMount () {

this.handleClick();

        fetch('./abtesting/abtestconfig.json').then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
          }).then(data => {
            // Work with JSON data here
            console.log(data);
          }).catch(err => {
            // Do something for an error here
            console.log("Error Reading data " + err);
          });
    }
}    
export default hot(module)(App);
```

Comment: just import the JSON directly `import MockData from './abtestconfig.json;`. You can mock a service by calling a function that returns a promise which resolves with the `MockData`.

Comment: Are you saying i don't need to use fetch etc.?

Comment: Correct. You will have to swap the promise out for `fetch` when you implement a real service though. But as long as you know the structure of your response, the transition should be pretty painless.

Comment: But I will be keeping this file in a server/external location in future. So, i thought to call as if i'm calling from external location for now itself, though this file has kept locally.

Comment: The thing you want to do is replicate a service call as much as possible. If you can spin up a local server and do that, that'd be great, but if you'd rather build out the rest of the data flow logic, then just importing the mock JSON data is adequate in my opinion.